# This is the output I get [Ljava.lang.Object;@20422e25

Tags: java

I want to get the content in the content model of alfresco to be displayed in my Eclipse. Below is my method from the Dictionary service:

```
@Override
public Collection<QName> getSubTypes(QName arg0, boolean arg1)
{   
    //qName = (ArrayList<QName>) model.put("Array is", arg0);
    qName.add(arg0);
    return qName;
}
```

And this is how I am calling the method on my test class:

```
        SampleTest sampleTest = new SampleTest();
//      WebScriptRequest webScriptRequest =null;     
//      webScriptRequest.getExtensionPath();;
//      String string = webScriptRequest.getExtensionPath();
        System.out.println("" + sampleTest.getSubTypes(ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT, true).toArray().toString());
```

Comment: and what's your question?

Comment: My question is based on the output I get , I am expecting data from alfresco not "[Ljava.lang.Object;@20422e25"

Answer (score 1):

`array.toString` prints the address of the array, not the elements in it.

you can use [java.util.Arrays.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) method to print the string

so your code should be like

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sampleTest.getSubTypes(ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT, true).toArray()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much StinePike, It is now displaying the content that I needed

Comment: Redundant concatenation of empty String to String.

Comment: @DaftPunk thanks for pointing.. :) .. I just copied his code thats why it was there

Comment: @user2567243 you are welcome :). Also welcome to stackoverflow. If you think any answer was helpful you can accept that

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to print the `Collection` ? You can convert it into an array and use either `Arrays.toString(arr)` or `Arrays.deepToString(arr)` :

```
Arrays.toString(
    sampleTest.getSubTypes(ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT, true).toArray());
```

What you are trying is :

```
.toArray().toString()
```

So it converts the `Collection` to an array and invokes the `toString()` on that array object , hence by default [Object#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) is called :

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> **getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Method `Arrays.toString()` is what you are looking for.
`.toString()` on an Object only gives you the Object represantation not the actual value as a String(if it is not overriden).

Comment: @user2567243 Accepting the right answer **IS** the proper way to say "Thank you, it is working now". To accept an answer click on the checkmark below votes count for that answer.